# Non-leptonic weak decay with $|\Delta T=3/2|$ suppression (from "Inward bound" Pais' book)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, weak-interaction, isospin-symmetry

In Abraham Pais' "Inward Bound" book at page 564 it is mentioned that if we describe the weak interactions with the usual current-current interaction (including Cabibbo angle) we still do not explain the suppression of non-leptonic decays with $|\Delta T=3/2|$. He says "No convincing mechanism for this suppression exists to these days. That is not good."
Is this still the situation? (the book is from 1986).
If not, what is the mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A most resounding ***no***, it is ***not*** *still the situation*. Mesonic effective theories were not properly understood at the time.

Even in 1986, the   dominance of $\Delta(T)=1/2$ was not a "scandal" as the previous generation of physicists had erroneously convinced themselves and declared, in the hope that a novel handle to the standard model would emerge out of such a "paradoxical discrepancy". Bad bet.

Already in  1987, [Bardeen, Buras, & Gerard, *PhysLett* **B192** (1987)  138-144](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(87)91156-7) solved the problem down to a level of messy/muddy low-energy QCD in the dual, mesonic, nonperturbative representation (*1/N*). A juicy technical problem, but definitely *not a scandal*.

Ever since, their picture has been triumphantly validated by lattice simulations, and its analytical features elegantly summarized in [BGB (2014), *EurPhysJou* **C74** 2871](https://doi.org/10.1140/epjc/s10052-014-2871-x).

While there are poorly understood messy issues, this is a tour de force of non-perturbative effective QCD and thoroughly belies Pais' implicit bet that this is a theoretical emergency of sorts, with great promises of radical paradigmatic insight. You may have glimpsed later papers on the subject, mumbling about unsettled issues, but this is only to justify their focus and legitimize the "problem" with spurious urgency. The promise of this as the gateway to low-energy QCD is long gone. Buchalla, Buras, & Lautebacher (1996) summarize

> There have been several attempts to explain the *I*=1/2 rule, which basically use the effective Hamiltonian  [...] but employ different methods for the hadronic matrix elements. In particular we would like to mention the *1/N* approach (Bardeen et al., 1987a), the work of Pich and de Rafael (1991) based on an effective action for four-quark operators, the diquark approach of Neubert and Stech (1991), QCD sum rules (Jamin and Pich, 1994), chiral perturbation calculations (Kambor et al., 1990, 1991), and [...]  an analysis (Antonelli et al., 1996) in the framework of the chiral quark model (Cohen and Manohar, 1984).

<sub>(PS: I am a great admirer of Pais's truly magnificent book as a history, but saddened by his concluding speculative overviews,   detracting from the dispositive majesty of the historical part. History has been very unkind to several misframings there. If only he had managed to chuck or finesse those in a final edition! I guess theorists cannot be restrained back from speculating...)</sub>